# AngularJs caching old view on user's computer

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browser-cache

I thought I resolved my caching issues by implementing gulp-rev, but to my surprise it seems that I didn't fully resolve them.  At present I'm cache busting my

```
app.js + angular controllers, etc... >>>> ang.[#hash].js
```

This seems to update the angular properties through hashing, however to my surprise I added a textarea in place of an input on a form and saw the old input post-release (and re-hashing) on my tester's computer.  Is this because the tester has an old templatecache?  How do I fix this undesirable behavior?

Comment: So, are the templates included in `etc...`, or not? How do you serve your templates?

Comment: @JB They are not, I'm not handling them at all right now (I plan to), however it seems that what's getting cached is my index.html after running some tests.  So index.html stays cached during deploys, which is default browser behavior (I can't tell my users to change their browser settings).  I'm thinking I'm going to do a hard refresh on logout and tell folks to logout to get new changes.  Dunno if there's a better way...

Comment: You need to disable caching for your index.html file (at server side), and for your templates too, until they're bundled with the JS.